# mysql get data by matching row of fixed position with strlength()

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where a filed contains roll numbers like so:

```
   id | roll_no
   --------------
   1  | 290320452
   2  | 290320453
   3  | 290340454
   4  | 290330455
```

from the above column I want roll_no with matching position 4 AND 5 with 32.
where the result would be

```
   id | roll_no
   --------------
   1  | 290320452
   2  | 290320453
```

For now I have done by filtering the result array like so:

```
    $subject_code = 32;    
    foreach($result as $row){
                    if($subject_code != NULL){
                        if(substr($row['roll_no'],3,2) == $subject_code){
                            $data[] = $row['roll_no'];
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $data[] = $row['roll_no'];
                    }
}
```

Is there a better way to filter while querying on mysql query.

I have seen SUBSTRING() function of mysql but no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select roll_no from your_table
where substring(cast(roll_no as char(11)), 4, 2) = '32'
```

Comment: That's a good answer, but I suspect it wouldn't be a fast query.  Obviously that can't be avoided with the current schema, but the OP needs to ask him/herself if the schema is right.  If you're interested in a particular substring within a column then that would suggest that that substring has some special significance, and it would be better stored in its own column.

Comment: @GordonM Its good to store on own column but these results are data imported from other software and I get bulk of roll_no which needs to be filtered based on the position of codes and they are predefined.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:
You can use `_ (underscore)` as wild card to match exact number of positions.

```
select
 id, roll_no 
from
 roll_numbers_table
where
 roll_no like '___32%'; // 3 underscores before 32
```

This statement on your sample data would result:

```
id | roll_no
--------------
1  | 290320452
2  | 290320453
```